# Use mobx and react get an error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, axios, mobx, mobx-react

In my mind, I want use mobx to save a state named mask, when I use axios, this state will be true and when i finshed call, this state will be false, below is my code

store.tsx

```
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from 'mobx';
import axios from 'axios';

class Store {

isHeaderShow = false;

isTabBarShow = false;

isShowingMovies = [];

isShowingMovieIds = [];

willShowingMovies = [];

willShowingMovieIds = [];

isLoading = false;


constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
}


getShowingMovies = async () => {
    if (this.isShowingMovies.length === 0) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/movie/ajax/movieOnInfoList`).then((res) => {
            return res.data;
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
        runInAction(() => {
            this.isShowingMovies = res.movieList;
            this.isShowingMovieIds = res.movieIds;
           
        })
    }
}
}

    const store = new Store();
    
    export default store
```

mask.tsx

```
import React, { useState, FC } from 'react'
import { Mask } from 'antd-mobile'
import store from '../../mobx/store'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const SimpleMask: FC = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    setVisible(store.isLoading);
    return (
        <>
            <Mask visible={visible} />
        </>
    )
}

export default observer(SimpleMask)
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './component/header'
import Footer from './component/footer'
import Mask from './component/mark'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='header'>
        <Header />
      </div>
      <div className='main'>This is main</div>
      <div className='footer'>
        <Footer />
      </div>
      <Mask/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "antd-mobile": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "mobx": "^6.4.2",
    "mobx-react": "^7.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

the error is below
[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTzYS.png)

Could u guys give me some advices? I'm first use react and mobx and want to improve.
Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setVisible` directly in your `Mask` component, which causes a re-render, which causes `setVisible` to be called again, and the infinite loop continues.

You could make it so that you only update the state when `store.isLoading` actually changes with the help of `useEffect`:

```js
const SimpleMask: FC = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setVisible(store.isLoading)
    }, [store.isLoading])

    return (
        <Mask visible={visible} />
    )
}
```

Or you could skip the `useState` entirely and just use your store straight away:

```js
const SimpleMask: FC = () => {
    return (
        <Mask visible={store.isLoading} />
    )
}
```